# mysql - separate entries or split string into individual characters

Tags: php, mysql

I have a attendance register database and website that's been running for over 3 years, it's suddenly been requested to be split into 8 sessions per attendance.

E.g. We have 50 different classes, each class holds 20 students, registration is taken 5 times per week

50 x 20 x 5 = 5000 registration entries per week

5000 x 40 = 200,000 entries per year

If we are suddenly splitting each registration into 8:

5000 x 8 = 40,000 registration entries per week.

40,000 x 40 = 1.6 million registration entries per year.

I don't think this would viable in the long run. So I was thinking we could squeeze all 8 session entries into one table cell then in php split the string into individual characters to check each attendance.

E.g.

Instead of:

```
RegID | ClassID | StudentID | Date | Session1 | Session2 | Session3 | Session4 | etc.

10000 | 120 | 150 | 2015-09-14 | / | O | D | X | etc.
```

It would be

```
RegID | ClassID | StudentID | Date | Registration

10000 | 120 | 150 | 2015-09-14 | /ODX//XX
```

Or maybe we could use `explode()`? 
So we'd have `/|O|D|X|/|/|X|X`

Each registration taken would only be a single character so splitting would be easy but which method would cause less strain on an already straining shared server? (my client's server, not mine).